# How to get the index of a clicked button

Tags: javascript, html

Good morning.

How can i get the index of a clicked button of a class. When i click on the first "Editar" i want the index 0. When i click on the second "Editar" i want the index 1 and so on. I tried to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('editar')
```

But i can't find the lenght of the clicked button.

This is the HTML. It is a table with just one row here, but in the page it's going to be a lot of rows:

```
        <div class="alinhadora">
          <tr>
            <td scope="row" class='zeroCol'>1</td>
            <td class='primeiraCol'>
              <p class='prioridadeCampo'></p>
              <textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="20" placeholder="Digite aqui a prioridade."></textarea>
            </td>
            <td class='segundaCol'>
              <p class='descri-tabela'></p>
              <label for="setorSelect"></label>
              <select name="setor" id="setorSelect" class='selectTotal'>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Tecnologia da Informação">Tecnologia da Informação</option>
                <option value="Recursos Humanos">Recursos Humanos</option>
                <option value="Engenharia">Engenharia</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class='terceiraCol'>
              <p class='areaCampo'></p>
              <label for="areaSelect"></label>
              <select name="area" id="areaSelect" class='selectTotal'>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Redes">Redes</option>
                <option value="Telefonia">Telefonia</option>
                <option value="Software">Software</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class='quartaCol'>
              <p class='tipoCampo'></p>
              <label for="tipoSelect"></label>
              <select name="tipo" id="tipoSelect" class='selectTotal'>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Liberação de Acesso">Liberação de Acesso</option>
                <option value="Dúvidas">Dúvidas</option>
                <option value="Desenvolvimento">Desenvolvimento</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class='quintaCol'>
              <p>Aberto</p>
            </td>
            <td class='sextaCol'>
              <p class='urgenciaCampo'></p>
              <label for="urgenciaSelect"></label>
              <select name="urgencia" id="urgenciaSelect" class='selectTotal'>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Normal">Normal</option>
                <option value="Urgente">Urgente</option>
                <option value="Crítico">Crítico</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class='setimaCol'>
              <p class='designadoCampo'></p>
              <label for="designadoSelect"></label>
              <select name="designado" id="designadoSelect" class='selectTotal'>
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="Ailton de Souza Junior">Ailton de Souza Junior</option>
                <option value="Carlos Henrique">Carlos Henrique</option>
                <option value="Crítico">Everson</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td class='oitavaCol'>
              <p>Descrição Teste</p>
            </td>
            <td class='nonaCol'>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success acoes-botao salvar">Salvar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success acoes-botao">Chat</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success acoes-botao editar">Editar</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger acoes-botao">Aprovação</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: i tried document.getElementsByClassName('editar').target.attributes but i can't find where is the index from the button. I put it inside of a onclick function.

Comment: I don't think `document.getElementsByClassName('editar')` has a `target` attribute and I don't think there a native index attribute that would keep track of an element's index within a certain class. I'd loop through all the elements in the class and compare to each to the clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a param to function like this from HTML.

```
<button onclick="clicked(1)">Button1<button/>
<script>
function clicked(param){
console.log(param)}
</script>
```